# Different column order/right justify column for small mobile device?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following html:

```
<ol class="log">
  <li class="row">
    <p class="col-1 time">
      17:45
    </p>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      Here’s a comment
    </div>
    <p class="col-1 menu-column">
      <a href="#">Edit</a>
    </p>
  </li>

  ...

</ol>
```

Here's what the layout looks like for a desktop:

[image: Desktop Layout]

And here's what the layout looks for a small mobile device:

[image: Mobile Layout]

What I'd like to be able to do is right justify the edit link against the time for the mobile device - so that it takes up just 2 rows (but maintain the original layout for larger devices). Is there a way to do this with css in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`order-*`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering) classes to reorder the columns.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ol class="log">
  <li class="row">
    <p class="col order-0 col-md-1 time">
      17:45
    </p>
    <div class="col-12 order-2 order-md-1 col-md-10">
      Here’s a comment
    </div>
    <p class="col order-md-2 col-md-1 menu-column text-right text-md-center">
      <a href="#">Edit</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Just another quick question, the edit link is centred. When it becomes the right-most column, it's in the centre of half the white space. Can I conditionally right justify it? Or maybe add another filler column that is only used for mobile layout?

Comment: Do you mean it is always in the center of its container?

Comment: The `<p>` element. Yes

Comment: I see, didn't read the "text-right text-md-left" properly. My css file was screwing it over - so I removed the style that was affecting it and set the class attribute to `col order-md-2 col-md-1 menu-column text-right text-md-center`. Thanks again

Comment: it is not working as shown edit hasnt changed position i dint   know why is has got a green tick

Comment: @nikhilsugandh could you explain why it does not working?

Comment: @mahan i ran it its not showing what exaclty the OP is wantin

Comment: @nikhilsugandh You should run it in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of

```
<div class="col-md-10">
```

It will change to full width when the display width is `992px`
So make it `<div class="col-xs-10">` or `<div class="col-10">` so that it will auto adjust to all display widths

Comment: Ah. I should have mentioned that I *want* the div to take up the full width (on the second line) for a small mobile device

Comment: Then try adding `float-right` class to the element which you what to justify right

Comment: I used to do that in Bootstrap 3. But the css broke when I moved to 4 (something to do with flexbox perhaps?). I haven't debugged `float-right` code yet because I thought maybe there was a better way. Hence the question